# JOSM Map Editor component

Tags: java, dictionary, editor, 2d

With the use of what is written editor component?
Where can I find the source code for drawing editor ?
I try to develop simple training map editor with fast interface and drawing, but I don't know how to do it with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOSM is built with the standard Java API. Thus, all graphical components are based on Swing which is the standard GUI toolkit included in Java runtime.

You can find the source code of JOSM at [various locations](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download#Source). The primary and official location is the SVN repository:

> svn co https://josm.openstreetmap.de/svn/trunk

JOSM editing and rendering system is powerful, so it is built thanks to many classes. You should have a look to the following ones to understand the basics required to render map objects and edit them:

```
org.openstreetmap.josm.gui.NavigatableComponent
org.openstreetmap.josm.gui.MapView

org.openstreetmap.josm.data.osm.visitor.paint.AbstractMapRenderer
org.openstreetmap.josm.data.osm.visitor.paint.WireframeMapRenderer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what JOSM uses. But have a look at GEF http://www.eclipse.org/gef/. It's a graphical editing framework.